# How to manually set the GUID for a VB6 Activex control

Tags: vb6, activex

Recently we have an issue where we have to modify an ActiveX control which is developed long back. Problem is, we lost the source code, but we found another version of the same control with a different GUID.

The requirement is to keep the old GUID as other products are using the same control. So we want to replace the new control GUID with old one.

Is it possible? If so please let me know how can I change the GUID of the Active X control in VB6.

Comment: If you are modifying the source for a DLL/OCX and if those modification do not change an existing interface and if you have a copy of the *current* DLL/OCX - Then simply select "Binary Compatibility" in the project properties & point it to the existing binary, VB6 will take care of the rest for you.

Comment: Thank you Alex. It's working..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't manually put the interface & class GUIDs into your application, but in your project settings you need to enable "Binary Compatibility" pointing to a DLL that has the interface & class GUIDs that you want to have your project use.

From the Visual Basic 6.0 Project Documentation Component Tools Guide, "[Providing a Reference Point for Binary Version Compatibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716311%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)":

> To specify a reference version of the component type library
>
> 1. Open the project.
> 2. From the **Project** menu, choose **Project Properties** to open the **Project Properties** dialog box, and select the **Component** tab.
> 3. Click **Binary Compatibility** to lock down the class IDs in the project.
>      **Note**   As explained in "Project Compatibility: Avoiding MISSING References," the **Project Compatibility** setting actually has nothing to do with the Version Compatibility feature.
> 4. Update the box at the bottom of the **Version Compatibility** frame with the full path and name of the most recent version of your component.
>
> Whenever you make a new executable from your component project, Visual Basic compares the new interfaces of your classes to the ones described in the file you have specified. Visual Basic updates the type library version number according to the level of compatibility between the interfaces.

For more information, be sure to read through all the sections in the "[Version Compatibility in ActiveX Components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733715%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)" portion of the documentation.